# Mockall - How to mock a function calling another function

Tags: rust, mocking

Suppose I have this trait which I am mocking using the Rust's [mockall](https://crates.io/crates/mockall) crate:

```
#[cfg(test)]
use mockall::automock;

#[cfg_attr(test, automock)]
trait MyTrait {
    fn foo1(&self) -> u32 {
        self.foo2(10)
    }
    fn foo2(&self, a: u32) -> u32 {
        a + 1
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    use mockall::predicate;

    #[test]
    fn test() {
        let mut m = MockMyTrait::new();
        m.expect_foo2().with(predicate::eq(5u32));
        m.expect_foo1().return_const(11u32);

        assert_eq!(m.foo1(), 11);
    }
}
```

My expectation here is that this is going to fail since the `foo2` is called with the value `10` instead of the expected `5`. However it succeeds. Is there a way to use this crate to test the internal workings of a function?

Answer (score 2):

You can't both mock the trait and test the same trait.

What you're trying to accomplish here is some weird half-mock to test the default method implementations. This is not something that `mockall` supports. If you mock the trait, it will add hooks and checks to the *whole* trait; default implementations will not be considered.

You will have to test your trait manually:

```
trait MyTrait {
    fn foo1(&self) -> u32 {
        self.foo2(10)
    }
    
    fn foo2(&self, a: u32) -> u32 {
        a + 1
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use std::cell::RefCell;
    
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn my_trait_default_foo1_calls_foo2_with_10_and_returns_foo2_result() {
        #[derive(Default)]
        struct Test { foo2_was_called_with: RefCell<Option<u32>> }
        impl MyTrait for Test {
            fn foo2(&self, a: u32) -> u32 {
                *self.foo2_was_called_with.borrow_mut() = Some(a);
                42
            }
        }
        
        let test = Test::default();
        let result = test.foo1();
        
        assert_eq!(result, 42);
        assert_eq!(*test.foo2_was_called_with.borrow(), Some(10));
    }

    #[test]
    fn my_trait_default_foo2_returns_incremented_argument() {
        struct Test;
        impl MyTrait for Test { }
        let test = Test;
        
        assert_eq!(test.foo2(0), 1);
        assert_eq!(test.foo2(5), 6);
        assert_eq!(test.foo2(42), 43);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using mock in wrong way. You do not depend on the behaviour of the actual implementation, instead, you create your own expectation and simulate the behaviour in each unit test.

In you example, you are missing the call to method and an associated return value.

You just create an expectation with [argument matchers](https://docs.rs/mockall/0.11.2/mockall/#matching-arguments) for this trait method signatures `fn foo2(&self, a: u32) -> u32`  by:

```rs
m.expect_foo2().with(predicate::eq(5u32))
```

However, you have to provide you own [returning values](https://docs.rs/mockall/0.11.2/mockall/#static-return-values) for this expectiation

```rs
m.expect_foo2().with(predicate::eq(5u32)).returning(|x| x + 1)
```

Finnaly, you have to realize your expectation by calling the method:

```rs
assert_eq!(m.foo2(5), 6);
```

The code means you are expecting a call to `foo2` with an input argument of `5u32` and will replace the `foo2` implementation with `|x| x + 1`.